# Samsung launcher - Switching desktop screens starts application

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have an application which starts some service in onCreate method in Application class. The problem is when I switch desktop on Samsung devices.

1. Put the Application icon on your desktop, to the edge.
2. Drag the desktop (switch to the next page) by starting the move on the application icon.
3. The Android call onCreate method on Application class (my service starts) but not call activity intent. So the application is not running, but the service is running now. :(

I think this is a Samsung hack for feeling faster launching applications. When you place your finger on the icon, Samsung will launch the application (initialize); but it's not yet instructed to view the activity. Only then does it realize that it was not a click, but a move. So it won't send an activity instruction.

It only happens on Samsung devices!!!

Is there a flag that tells me that the application is not running? Then I could stop running the service.

Moving the start of the service to the activity does not seem to me a good solution.I would like to solve it so that the onCreate method is not called.

**Update information:**

It only happens on Samsung with Android Oreo (8.x) and lower. I tested it on Samsung J7 Android 8.1.0. On my Samsung J3 Android 9 it's not happend (onCreate method is called but service not started).

Comment: What wrong with the service being started with an Activity present?

Comment: It is a service that keeps the application still running. Thus, such a service should be called when the application starts, that means in onCreate in application class.